# Problems with growing a div in jQuery (relative and absolute divs)

Tags: jquery, css

i have a parent div that contains some random pictures that is in child divs about 7 or more. my aim is to have the parent div expand when the child divs populate it at random. note child divs can be 0 to 10 or more. 
the problem im having is that the parent div does not grow. i try using css and jquery and this is what i have so far
jquery

```
var margin = 5;

var blocks = [];
function align() {
$('.block').each(function(i){
    var min = Array.min(blocks);
    var index = $.inArray(min, blocks);
    var posleft = margin+(index*(300+margin));
    $(this).css({
        'left':(posleft+2)+'px',
        'top':min+'px'
    });
    blocks[index] = min+$(this).outerHeight()+margin;
}); 
}

function divlayOut() {
blocks = [];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    blocks.push(margin);
}
align();
}

Array.min = function(array) {
return Math.min.apply(Math, array);
};
```

html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.block{
width: 250px;
float:left; 
position:absolute;
}
.parent{
width: 800px; 
float:left; 
padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;
position:relative; 
}
</style>

</head>
<body onload="align();">
<div class="parent">
<div class="block">pic1 size H 100 x W 80</div>
<div class="block">pic1 size H 80 x W 800</div>
<div class="block">pic1 size H 300 x W 100</div>
<div class="block">pic1 size H 110 x W 90</div>
</div>
```

hope the picture below helps to clear what my aim is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are floating your picture, right? Read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

The floats are causing their parents to 'forget about the elements' and thus not expanding.

Summarized: add `overflow: auto;` to the parent, like so:

```
.parent {overflow: auto;}
```

Comment: tried this same result.. does not work. only different is the parent does not expand. i even remove float from them

Comment: Can you post a test case then?

Comment: where and how,, i must add if dont use jquery it works but i need juery to help with the alignment

Answer (score 0):

Because the child blocks are absolute positioned the parent block will never expand. You can use Jquery to manually calculate the height of the parent block (using child_block_height, blocks per row and block_width parameters) or you can use a float:left property for child block (non-absolute positioned).

Another way is to use inline-block elements: http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

I usually use the following way:

```
<style>
  .parent {
    overflow:hidden;
    *height:1%;
  }
  .block {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
</style>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried this same result.. does not work. only different is the parent does not expand. i even remove float from them..i must add if dont use jquery it works but i need juery to help with the alignment

Answer (score 0):

Do the child divs **need** to be absolutely positioned?

Take a look at this fiddle which uses `float:left` and css `clearfix` trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/5FXs2/

Comment: when i make the child absolute it does not work.yes they need to be in order for jquery to take proper effect

Comment: What is the purpose of the jQuery?  It appears it is only for layout purposes.  If that's the case, then why use jQuery instead of the proper application of HTML and CSS?